# I have a table in jsp which have 5 rows and 3 colums and i wanted to print it in servlet how can i do this?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp, servlets

```
<script>
function addRow() {

    var medicinename = document.getElementById("medicinename");
    var time = document.getElementById("time");
    var duration = document.getElementById("duration");
    var when = document.getElementById("when");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= medicinename.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= time.value;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= duration.value;
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= when.value;
    document.getElementById('medicinename').value='';
    document.getElementById('time').value='';
    document.getElementById('duration').value='';
    document.getElementById('when').value='';
}

function deleteRow(obj) {

    var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    table.deleteRow(index);

}

function addTable() {

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");

    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    table.border='1';

    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);

    for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
       var tr = document.createElement('TR');
       tableBody.appendChild(tr);

       for (var j=0; j<4; j++){
           var td = document.createElement('TD');
           td.width='75';
           td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + i + "," + j));
           tr.appendChild(td);
       }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);

}

</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Medicine Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="medicinename"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Time:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="time">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Duration:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="duration">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>When?</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="when">
        <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="Javascript:addRow()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="mydata">
<table id="myTableData"  border="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><b>Medicine Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Medicine Time&nbsp</b></td>
        <td><b>Medicine Duration</b></td>
        <td><b>Medicine When?</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here is JAVASCRIPT through which i add element in JSP table
here is my 4 field and table which display data inside JSP
    hello = request.getParameter("");//what should i take here
                System.out.println(hello);

Comment: @Burning as a whole table

Comment: @Utkarsh wait i posted it.

Comment: is this possible @Crystal

Comment: is this possible @Utkarsh

Comment: @Utkarsh sir i know what u say that...but really dont k now about Ajax call to send this data to your servlet...can u plz help about this.i will be thankful to you

Comment: You changed the question completely again. Now my answer is irrelevant to your question. You should have asked a new question

Comment: how can i  ask a new question...i am still on there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in another answer, either use `input` elements in form or use `JSON` object as given in another answer here.

**Form input method**

**HTML or JSP**

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Medicine Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="medicinename"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Time:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="time">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Duration:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="duration">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>When?</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="when">
            <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="Javascript:addRow()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="mydata">

    <form action="yourServletName" method="post">
    <table id="myTableData"  border="1" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><b>Medicine Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Medicine Time&nbsp</b></td>
            <td><b>Medicine Duration</b></td>
            <td><b>Medicine When?</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="button" >Submit</button>
    <!-- Update the rowCount on Submitting the button -->
     <input type="hidden" id="rowCount" value="" />
    </form>
   </div>
```

JS File to add input in table, you can  :

```
function addRow() {

    var medicinename = document.getElementById("medicinename");
    var time = document.getElementById("time");
    var duration = document.getElementById("duration");
    var when = document.getElementById("when");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="'+'rowMedicine'+rowCount+'" value="'+medicinename.value+'" readonly />';
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="'+'rowTime'+rowCount+'" value="'+time.value+'" readonly />';
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="'+'rowDuration'+rowCount+'" value="'+duration.value+'" readonly />';
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="'+'rowWhen'+rowCount+'" value="'+when.value+'" readonly />';
    document.getElementById('medicinename').value='';
    document.getElementById('time').value='';
    document.getElementById('duration').value='';
    document.getElementById('when').value='';
}

function deleteRow(obj) {

    var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    table.deleteRow(index);
}

function addTable() {

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");

    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    table.border='1';

    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);

    for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
       var tr = document.createElement('TR');
       tableBody.appendChild(tr);

       for (var j=0; j<4; j++){
           var td = document.createElement('TD');
           td.width='75';
           td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + i + "," + j));
           tr.appendChild(td);
       }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);

}
```

In your servlet, use the `request.getParameter` to access values.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Now, you can get the parameter from input elements using name
    String rowMedicine  = request.getParameter("rowMedicine1");
    //Similarly get the values of all parameters using names 

    //get the row count 
    //iterate through it and save it in your database


}
```

Comment: null is returnd in servlet console

Comment: Did you update your jsp or html, I have added  HTML from in the jsp ? Provide your servlet code.

Comment: NULL is Returnd in servlet console

Comment: String rowMedicine  = request.getParameter("rowMedicine1");
   System.out.println(rowMedicine); in servlet

Comment: Still same the result

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect your table data in `JavaScript` by the  use a `form` or `Ajax`  to send this data to your servlet. You can't get the table data from request parameters in `servlet` unless you send it.

An example of form

```
<form action="login" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uname"  placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
<button type="submit" class="button" >Login</button>
</form>
```

This form pass `uname` and `password` to login `Servlet`.

You can pass each data in table like this way...!
In servlet side you can use this code for fetch data

```
String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```

just try out..!

Comment: i know that but i have table

Answer (score 1):

Since, you were using jQuery and Servlet but you edited your question and removed the code. But here is some code example using jQuery.

Sample Table :

```
 <table id='table_id'>
        <th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td><td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

First you need to iterate through your table in javascript, create a JSON object with table data. Probably like this (see the table structure given here)

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function collectData(){
        var tableData = [];
        $('#table_id tr').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var tds = $this.find('td');
            var i = 0;
            //if we have data in that row
            if(tds.length){
                var rowData = {
                    column1:tds[0].innerHTML,
                    column2:tds[1].innerHTML,
                }
                tableData.push(rowData);
            }
        });
        console.log(tableData);

       // Send it via AJAX

        $.ajax({
             url: '/yourServletName', // Change name to your servlet
             type: 'POST', 
             dataType: 'json',
             data: {objarray: JSON.stringify(tableData)},
             success: function(result) {
                alert('SUCCESS');
             }
        });
    }
```

JSON will be like :

```
{
  [{'column1':1,'column2':2}, {'column1':3,'column2':4}]
}
```

Now in your servlet code access this data using

```
 String tableArray = request.getParameter("objarray").
```

But you need to convert the JSON to Java Pojo Object. Create a class similar to your table and parse the JSON using any library like jackson or [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
public class TableData{
   private String column1;
   private String column2;

   public String getColumn1(){
        return column1;
   }

   public void setColumn1(String column1){
        this.column1 = column1;
   }

   public String getColumn2(){
        return column2;
   }

   public void setColumn2(String column2){
        this.column2 = column2;
   }
}
```

GSON tutorial is given [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Comment: thanx a lot.i stucked with my code thats why i edited for getting better solution...well thanx for help i try it and let you know.

Comment: yep.but not getting.see i have 4 field in jsp and one button when i press button all my textfield contains data are stored in table it is only for jsp it worked good.but my question is i want to catch that table which i filled should be printed.but don't know how can i catch the parameter and which parameter.and about AJAX and JSON i really dont know about that.wait i update my code just check it